# overload sorting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with two fields: a `string` field and a `numeric` field.

First the ordering must be by `value`.

In case of being tied with another, another order must be made by `key`.

I think it is an overload of the ordering.

```
present = {
    '35':10,
    '20':10,
    '10':50
}
sortedPresent = sorted(present.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
```

The output is:

```
[('10', 50), ('35', 10), ('20', 10)]
```

Expected output:

```
[('10', 50), ('20', 10), ('35', 10)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sortedPresent = sorted(present.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0]))
# We sort by tuples as described
#      https://www.peterbe.com/plog/in-python-you-sort-with-a-tuple
# Note for tuple as key:
#   -k[1] is descending order by number
#   k[0] is ascending order by string
print(sortedPresent)
```

**Output**

```
[('10', 50), ('20', 10), ('35', 10)]
```